# How to Populate a Multi-column Combobox via code?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

On my Access form I have an empty combobox with it's `Row Source Type` set to `Table/Query`, and Bound Column set to `1`.

What I want to do is via code, to fill this combobox with two columns, where it displays the first column to the user and then in code I'll fetch the value from the second column.

My question is, how do I fill the columns?  I know how to fill the combobox if the `Row/Source` is set to `Value List` - but that's just a flat list; I want two columns here.

I cannot use a separate query/table for the column data because I am generating it dynamically.  Basically, I am filling the combobox with a list of edit field control names and their captions.  The user selects the caption name from the combobox and then I can fetch the control name.

I just need to know how to add data to columns in the combobox.

So, I figure something like this (I know this is incorrect, but you can see what I am trying to accomplish):

```
Me.mycombobox.AddItem("column 1 data";"column2 data")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add this into to your event that will trigger the combobox being filled it should shed some light on your question:

```vb
Me.Combo0.RowSource = "Row1Column1;Row1Column2;Row2Column1;Row2Column2"
```

Make sure that your `Column Count` is set to 2 for this example. Basically you will just build a string formatted like the one in the example filled with the contents that you want to be filled into the combobox. Then just assign it to your Combobox's `RowSource`.

Basically when you input 6 items as the RowSource:

```vb
Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5, Item6
```

It will shift based on what you have the `Column Count` is set to, for example if the column count is set to 3, the above list will turn into:

```vb
Item1 Item2 Item3 
Item4 Item5 Item6
```

If the column count is set to 2 then it will turn into:

```vb
Item1 Item2 
Item3 Item4
Item5 Item6
```

**Note:** Make sure that you set the `Row Source Type` to "Value List".

Comment: That's how I was doing it - but that creates a single-column list, not a multi-column table.

Comment: Make sure you have the `Column Count` set, if you don't then you will just get one column.  Also check the `Column Widths` property, if it is set to something like `2cm;0cm` then you will only see the first column even though the second one is technically still there.

Comment: In the sample I have given you it will show you 2 rows with 2 columns.  I will edit my answer to provide a visualization for how it works.

Comment: So it automatically divides for us.  Okay, this is working!  Thanks!

Comment: @BGM No problem, it was an interesting question!

Comment: Also, I had to set the `Row Source Type` to `Field Values` instead of `Table/Query`. - Just a note for anyone who comes upon this.

Comment: @BGM Whoops, forgot to mention that part. I will update my post.